# Surface of 3D Triangle

Tags: geometry, 3d, vectors, area

The coordinates $A(-1,0,2), B(2,-1,3)$ and $C(4,0,1)$ are the corners in the triangle $ABC$.

- a) Find the length of the sides in the triangle.
- b) Find the area of the triangle.

Now I'm able to solve the first one, and I also did manage to find the area using the Law of Cosines, but this leaves me with a decimal answer $(A \approx 4.74)$, when my book says I should be able to get the exact answer $3\sqrt{10}/2$.

Any ideas on how I achieve this?

Comment: Hi again @Mikal, please consider accepting the answer in order to the question to appear as closed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick two of the sides of the triangle, for example:

$$\vec{AB} = \vec{OB}-\vec{OA} = (3,-1,1), \quad \vec{AC} = \vec{OC}-\vec{OA} = (5,0,-1).$$

Then compute the area as follows:

> $$ \color{green}{A} = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2} | \vec{AB} \wedge  \vec{AC} | }= \frac{1}{2} \left| \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
> \vec{\imath} & \vec{\jmath} & \vec{k} \\
> 3 & -  1 & 1 \\
> 5 & 0 & -1 \\
> \end{array}\right| \right| = \frac{1}{2}|(1,8,5)|=\color{green}{\frac{\sqrt{90}}{2}} \ \blacksquare$$

The blue formula comes from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning).

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I would say that $\frac{1}{2}|(1,8,5)|=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{90}=\color{green}{3}\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks @georg, I don't know what I was thinking!

Comment: That's great and thanks for the answers, but because I'm used to different notation, could you explain the the middle part of the equation?

Comment: What part do you mean exactly? Is it the $\wedge$ symbol?

Comment: No sorry I figured it out through this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsgK1d-_8ik. It turns out I've never learned this thing before now